# Adding a CABasicAnimation to a subclassed UIButton - if enabled

Tags: swift, uibutton, autolayout, subclass, cabasicanimation

I am having problems with Autolayout and a subclassed UIButton. In my UIButton subclass, I override isEnabled to add a color animation when the button is enabled. See below.

```
// Within my subclassed button:
override var isEnabled:Bool {
    didSet {
        UIChanges.colorButton(buttonToFade: self)
    }
}

// colorButton to be called from UIChanges:
static func colorButton(buttonToFade:UIView) {
    let colorAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "backgroundColor")
    colorAnimation.duration = 1
    colorAnimation.fromValue = UIColor.black.cgColor
    colorAnimation.toValue = UIColor.white.cgColor
    colorAnimation.repeatCount = 10
    colorAnimation.autoreverses = true
    buttonToFade.layer.add(colorAnimation, forKey: nil)
}
```

The problem is, this animation never occurs.

**How can I add this colorButton() animation to the subclassed button *only* if it's enabled?**

I presume this has something to do with autolayout, because if I put that function within layoutSubviews, it works fine.

EDIT:
I added a new button to the View Controller that manually changes the subclassed button to enabled, and @JD. answer works fine (the CABasicAnimation fires). However, the CABasicAnimation does not fire if that tester button isn't pressed. This button I am trying to adjust gets enabled mostly in AppDelegate - so could this be a cause of the problem? The button frame isn't loaded when the button gets sets to enabled? Autolayout issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding your animation code in UIView or CALayer Extension, then call function from custom UIButton.

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    override var isEnabled:Bool {
        didSet {
            if isEnabled {
                setTitle("Enable", for: .normal)
                layer.colorButton()
            } else {
                setTitle("Disable", for: .normal)
                layer.removeAllAnimations()
            }
        }
    }
}

extension CALayer {

    func colorButton() {
        let colorAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "backgroundColor")
        colorAnimation.duration = 1
        colorAnimation.fromValue = UIColor.black.cgColor
        colorAnimation.toValue = UIColor.white.cgColor
        colorAnimation.repeatCount = 10
        colorAnimation.autoreverses = true
        add(colorAnimation, forKey: nil)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Still nothing. The animation does not appear when the button is enabled.

Comment: Are you assigned subclass in Identity Inspector?

Comment: Yes, I have it set to the subclassed button class in Identity Inspector. I edited my question. Your answer works fine IF i have a separate button that changes the subclass button state to enable. It does not work if I don't have that button (like in your animation). Could it be because this button is getting enabled in AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions? The button frame isn't set for the CABasicAnimation? Autolayout issue?

Comment: No. You can enable from app delegate also.